# CSS3 Heading Issue

Tags: html, css

I am scratching my head to resolve this issue but without success.
It is very simple: a `div` with rounded corners with a `h3` on the top (I am trying to simulate a panel with title),  very simple.

For some reason, the `h3` always has a space, feels like it has a margin or something.

```css
.example-wrapper {
     border: 1px solid #555;
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;}
    
.example-wrapper h3 {
      background: #555;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;}
```

```html
<DIV class="example-wrapper">
    <H3>Herry Potter</H3>
</DIV>
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

You can find the issue [here](http://www.cssdesk.com/N7jEy).

Comment: Tag names should be lower-case: <div> instead of <DIV>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `H#` has margins by default. Set `H3{ margin: 0; }` to solve it. You can always use developer tools to inspect elements and see any style applied to them.